# NuGet package for ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget

I have recently started to use NuGet and I was wondering if there is an asp.net mvc 3 package that I can install so that I do not have to reference the aspnet mvc3 assemblies via a lib folder like the traditional way with all references set to CopyLocal = true. At the moment I have the following assemblies in my lib folder:

```
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
System.Web.Helpers.dll
System.Web.Mvc.dll
System.Web.Razor.dll
System.Web.WebPages.Administration.dll
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
System.Web.WebPages.dll
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio 2010 SP1, you can right click on the project and select "Add Deployable Assemblies". Select the ASP.NET MVC 3 option. That'll add the MVC assemblies to a special directory which will ensure they are in the bin directory when building/publishing your web application.

Comment: oh thats a new one Phil..didn't know that ... cheers ... but I still wonder why do we have to go down this new route, why not simply have an nuget package and put these assemblies in the packages folder

Comment: We're looking into that option. We ran into some...non-technical difficulties while investigating that.

Comment: It does not work with Class Library projects. Seems NuGet is still the best choice if available.

Comment: Wait...*Non*-technical difficulties?

Comment: @DanM aka issues from "the man" but clearly those hurdles were resolved.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic, ahh thanks for clarifying :) And thanks for bringing my attention back to this thread...sounds like we no longer need to add deployable assemblies.

Comment: @DanM that was the reason i ended up on this thread, i was confused at who moved my cheese in VS2012 when i went to add those deployable dependencies

Answer (score 8):

Looks like the "aspnetmvc" NuGet package is what you're looking for.

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/aspnetmvc

N.B. This isn't an official package from Microsoft, but one created by a member of the community.

Comment: Well I actually found this one but this does not install it as a package like others, it uses some thing called chocolaty which simply installs asp.net mvc on the machine as oppose to in the package folder of the solution

Comment: Didn't realize that. @Haacked's solution is your best bet then.

Answer (score 8):

If you're coming across this question now, the other solutions will likely no longer work for VS2012, VS2013, and beyond. Instead, I found adding the correct NuGet package worked seamlessly:

In `Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console`:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 3.0.50813.1
```

[This package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/3.0.50813.1) is owned by Microsoft, and trustworthy.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note for upgrading to **MVC4**

If you are still using bin deployables (“Add Deployable Assembly”) for your current ASP.NET MVC setup .. you should remove it and replace it with the **AspNetMvc nuget package**.