# Why there is no proper NuGet package for ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nuget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NuGet package for ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981458/nuget-package-for-asp-net-mvc-3)

Why there is not a proper NuGet package for ASP.NET MVC 3 from the MS team? Why is there a new  "Add Deployable Assemblies" option when the team itself promoting nuget for packaging? Doesn't make sense at all ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, considering you've already commented on [Haack's own response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981458/nuget-package-for-asp-net-mvc-3/5986055#5986055) I'm not sure what you really expect to get other than his own recommendation. I'm sure they (or a community member) will submit a more polished package at some point if possible.