# mvc 3 azure webrole in VWD 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, visual-web-developer, webrole

I want to add a MVC 3 Webrole in my Azure project. But I am not able to find a mvc3 template in visual web developer when I go to add dialog from "Add new web role". When it comes to mvc project only mvc 2 web role is available.
I have the latest version and updates of vwd 2010 (installed just last week) and also mvc 3 toolkit is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update - seems like this is a known problem - here's one rather nasty workaround - http://www.jimandkatrin.com/CodeBlog/post/MVC3-in-Azure.aspx

Alternatively, just create your web application as a "normal project" and then afterwards add it as an existing role to your cloud project.

After you've done this you will need to make sure you "copy local" the necessary mvc3 assemblies - similar to http://datachomp.com/archives/deploy-mvc3-to-shared-hosting/

---

One possibility - check that you have ".Net Framework 4" selected in your dialog - if you have 3.5 selected then MVC3 won't show up.

---

The only other possibility I can think of is that it's an install issue - does the MVC3 show up when you just try create a new web app? (not using Azure).

Comment: I checked under Framework 4 > Web. MVC 3 not there. Not an install issue either cos I am able to see new mvc 3 web application - ie the non-azure one.

Comment: Thanks - I've just updated my answer - seems like it's a known problem :(

Comment: Also phil haack has noted in vs2010 sp1 therefor a new right click option to add the mvc3 assemblies to a folder for deployment with the application. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981458/nuget-package-for-asp-net-mvc-3/5986055#5986055

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure Web Role templates don't yet have MVC3 supported directly. However, Steve Marx published a [blog post](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/asp-net-mvc-in-windows-azure) about how to do this with today's tools, showing two ways to easily set up MVC3 in a Web Role. For a third option, look at [this post](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/windows-azure-startup-tasks-tips-tricks-and-gotchas) showing how to run the web platform command line installer (just run it for MVC3).

**EDIT**: One more option is to use Jason Haley's Visual Studio MVC3 Template for Azure. See his blog post [here](http://jasonhaley.com/blog/post/2011/03/22/How-to-Add-MVC-3-Project-Types-to-the-Azure-Cloud-Service-Wizard.aspx) for documentation and download links.