# System.web.webpages run error after install Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

WE have a web application in MVC 3, and Visual Studio 2010, and now we installed the Visual Studio 2012, and find a problem with the dll "System.Web.WebPages", now it is in version 2.0.0.0 , and before is 1.0.0.0.

In my computer with both Visual Studios there is no problem, but if I publish the project and create a application directory in IIS, in another computer, without Visual Studios, the following error is throwed in web browser:

```
**Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.**
```

We've tried to put the dll in the publish folder and the same problem is happening.
We've tried to put the following code in web.config too:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>
```

OBS: I'm publishing the project in Visual Studio 2010. **Dont** using the Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because of assembly reference or configuration issues. You can easily fix it by executing the following command in nuget console (`Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console`).

```
Install-Package AspNetMvc -Version 3.0.20105.0
```

It will automatically add all the required references and configures it. Once the installation completes, rebuild and publish the application.

---

If you're using Visual Studio 2010 SP1, you can right click on the project and select "Add Deployable Assemblies". Select the ASP.NET MVC 3 option. That'll add the MVC assemblies to a special directory which will ensure they are in the bin directory when building/publishing your web application.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5986055/540345)

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem.
But I did not understand why this problem happened after I installed vs 2012, you can tell me?

Comment: That means, the publish was working in a single go before installing vs-2012? I believe, the problem was not because of vs-2012 installation. You might be missing something in the loop.